# elm.Attribute("").Value не равно

Tags: c#, winforms, xml

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает:

```
if (elm.Attribute("name").Value == comboBox1.Text)

if (elm.Attribute("name").Value == dataGridView1.SelectedRows.ToString())
```

Но работает, с тем же содержанием:

```
if (elm.Attribute("name").Value == "текст")

if (elm.Attribute("name").Value == textBox2.Text)
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, вы неправильно обращаетесь к элементам, попробуйте вот так

```cs
// comboBox1.SelectedItem - выбранный элемент комбобокса
if (elm.Attribute("name").Value == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

```cs
// вам же с ячейкой надо сравнить?
if (elm.Attribute("name").Value == dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString())
// обратите внимание, что если ни одна ячейка в таблице не выделена, вы получите исключение
// нужно предворительно проверить dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count != 0
```

Comment: comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() пробовал и ToString тоже ко всему, интересно, что я могу из comboBox1 получить в текстовое окно значение и если прировнять его к elm.Attribute("name").Value оно не сработает, а вот если просто текст вписать туда, то сработает.

Comment: if (elm.Attribute("name").Value == dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) не работает. А dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect; мне не подходит, мне конкретный столбец необходим. Но предпочтительнее вариант с comboBox1 вообще. Черт с ней, с таблицей.

Comment: @Velen Попробуйте вот такую строчку `MessageBox.Show(elm.Attribute("name").Value + "\r\n" + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())` Сравните строчки визуально. НУ и для остальных случаев пробуйте этот же способ.

Comment: @Velen С таблицей еще можно так, на случай если ячейка одна выделена, а не строка `dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString())`

Comment: [Сведения об отладке кода C# с помощью Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Comment: elm.Attribute("name").Value == dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString() помогло, странно, но мне казалось я всё перепробовал и это тоже, но нет! Осталось решить вопрос с comboBox1

Comment: @Velen попробуйте еще это `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`, я поправил ответ.

Comment: comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() не работает, вот не понимаю логики, почему. Если с Cells понятно в чём я ошибся, выбрав Row, то здесь не понимаю.

Comment: @Velen тогда покажите, как вы наполняете `ComboBox`

Comment: `XmlNodeList combo = doc.GetElementsByTagName("toy");
            for (int i = 0; i < combo.Count; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(combo[i].Attributes["name"].Value + "\n");
            }`

Comment: @Velen уберите `+ "\n"`, и все заработает, либо при сравнении надо `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim()`

Comment: вообще огонь, решил больше вопросов чем нужно, спасибо!